# AngularJS: Two selects, options for second select should be subset of options on first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two angular dropdowns for the same source array of integers, say 1,2,3,4,5.
1st one should shows all numbers in the source array. 
2nd one should show only those numbers less than the number selected on the first.

```
    <select ng-model="model.IndexNumber" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in model.Numbers" ng-change="onChange()"/>
    <select ng-model="model.IndexLessThan" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in $scope.LessThanNumbers" ng-disabled="$scope.LessThanNumbers===null"/>
```

Here is how my javascript for onChange looks like this:

```
    $scope.onChange = function() {
    if ($scope.model.IndexNumber != null) {
        $scope.LessThanNumbers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.Numbers.length; i++) {
            if (i < $scope.model.IndexNumber) {
                $scope.LessThanNumbers.push($scope.model.Numbers[i]);
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    }
}
```

My LessThanNumbers array gets filled correctly.
But I have problem with second select getting updated with the options from it.
I am also not able to get the second select disabled before the first selection is made. I dont know what I am missing here.
I am pretty new to angular. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in your markup. You need to close `<select>` elements. Also, don't prefix model variables with `$scope`, it is implied from the context of Angular expressions. Last, there is a typo in the second `ng-options` definition (`k as as v`). Here is the correct version ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fu6hey0r/2/)) :

```
<select ng-model="model.IndexNumber" 
    ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in model.Numbers" 
    ng-change="onChange()"></select>
<select ng-model="model.IndexLessThan" 
    ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in LessThanNumbers" 
    ng-disabled="LessThanNumbers == null"></select>
```

FYI, the Angular way would be to use a filter on the `model.Numbers`, as demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/az27yohn/). This will allow you to take advantage of the digest phase that occurs when you select your number in the first dropdown, avoiding unnecessary event plumbing.

Comment: Thanks. I got the disabling, enabling to work. But the second dropdown is still empty.

Comment: There was a typo in your code I didn't see. Updated my answer.

Comment: oh needless to say I had realized and corrected it on my running code but not here. But still no luck. I can see it on the options in the inspect elemet but they just dont appear on my dropdown. My ng-app runs on a dom element in an MVC application if that affects anything.

Comment: This is very surprising, I got your code to work with little effort. Do you see any errors in the console ? Maybe you need to post some more Javascript.

Comment: Try removing the `$scope.$apply()` call, it is unnecessary as the `ng-change` directive takes care of triggering the digest cycle.

Comment: my code runs in a cshtml page and that seems to be the reason my dropdown does not refresh. Any experiences with that scenario?

Comment: Well, it can be anything that's involved in building the markup and script. If you're using C# or VB instructions that manipulate the content of your CSHTML page in an unexpected way, it can indeed break your Javascript. That's why I think you need to post more code.

Comment: ok figured it was a chosen attribute that was on my select that was hindering the refresh. so working fine now.

Comment: @slacker Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

avoid '$scope' on html tag

```
<select ng-model="model.IndexLessThan" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in LessThanNumbers" ng-disabled="LessThanNumbers===null">
```